# Restler3: DELETE Body JSON

Tags: php, json, restler, http-delete

I really don't understand what I should do to make a DELETE request.
I want to use JSON as in/output only, so also a DELETE request should receive JSON.
But that doesn't make the goal:

```
public function delete($request_data = NULL)
```

$request_data is nil every time. I'm trying it by using cURL:

```
curl -X DELETE http://…/API/index.php/test.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"test","value":"1337"}'
```

Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: some servers does not accept request body for DELETE method, check out docs for your http server.

Comment: Soo… what do you recommend to do to make it working with the most servers?